# programmatically validate a text field for mobile number

Tags: vb.net

in my application I need to validate mobile number text field in different forms. so I wish to write a
function for this purpose.my needs are:

text field accept **only numbers(0-9)**.
error message will shown if any **other characters are entered**.
does't allow space but **allow ctrl+c,ctrl+v,ctrl+x ans back sapce**.
if **ctrl+v(paste)** is done it will check whether the string contains **characters**, if yes then **display error message**.
does anyone can help me to write such a function in limited number of code?

I had validated the following

```
Private Sub mob_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles stok.KeyPress
If Asc(e.KeyChar) < 48 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 57 Then ' check whether the keypress is a number
mob.ForeColor = Color.green 
Else
mob.ForeColor = Color.Red
end if
end sub

Private Sub mob_LostFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles stok.KeyPress
if mob.text="" then 'for check empty space
end sub
```

but this is not what I need. I need all the process executed within a function

Comment: ie,you mean a single function for mobile number validation.

Comment: As a suggestion from a user perspetive: DO allow whitespace, but strip it when validating. It is a trivial step to do, but eases entering number enormously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Sub mob_validation(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs, ByVal mob As TextBox)
If e.KeyChar = Chr(22) Then
Dim output As String = New String((From c As Char In Clipboard.GetText.ToString Select c Where Char.IsLetter(c)).ToArray())
If output = "" And Len(mob.Text) = 10 Then
mob.ForeColor = Color.Green
Else
mob.ForeColor = Color.Red
Clipboard.Clear()
End If
Else
If Asc(e.KeyChar) < 48 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 57 Then
If Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 8 Then
If Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 3 Then
e.Handled = True
mob.ForeColor = Color.Red
End If
End If
Else
mob.ForeColor = Color.Green
End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: For which country? Documentation?

Comment: which meets the requirements in the question. for mobile nos without country code(10 digit)

Comment: it can applicable for all countries without country code.

Comment: Does it work with Paste command from mouse right-click menu? Or with shift+insert key combination?

Answer (score 1):

I think a regular expression would be best for your needs, take a look at this:

http://www.authorcode.com/how-to-use-regular-expression-for-validating-phone-numbers-in-net/

As a side note: I find the Asc(e.KeyChar) extremely ugly, I would parse the char to an int and see what happens: If int.TryParse() fails: error, if not: well it's a number.